# How to get the first tag containing a word with xpath?

Tags: xpath

How can I get the first button which has type, class, id or ANYTHING containing text (have a substring equal to) `close` or `Close` or `CLOSE`? I tried this:

```
//button[contains(text(),'close')]
```

but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate was testing whether any `text()` nodes contained "close". However, attributes are not `text()` nodes.

You can adjust your predicate to match on any attribute, then use a predicate on those attributes to test whether it's `name()` is "type", "class" or "id" and that it's `lower-case()` value contains "close":

With **XPath 2.0** you could use this:

```
//button[@*[ name() = ('type','class','id') and contains(lower-case(.), 'close') ]]
```

With **XPath 1.0,** it takes a little more work. You can translate the upper-case letters into lower-case letters:

```
//button[
    @*[name() = 'type' or name() = 'class' or name() = 'id']
      [contains(translate(.,'CLOSE','close'), 'close')]]
```

Comment: thank you.I found the line which does what I wanted: `(//button[@*[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'close')]])[1] | (//button[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'close')])[1]`